# Calling a method on a temporary object

Tags: c++

I've had a little problem with calling a operator on a temporary object. I've stripped the code to the essential problem:

```
template<typename T, typename OP>
struct X
{
    X( const OP &op ) : m_op( op ) { }
    X &operator ()( T *pa, size_t n ) { /* ... */ return *this; }
    OP m_op;
};

int main()
{
//  Why does this work ...
    ((X<int, less<int>>)( less<int>() ))( nullptr, 123 );

//  ... this doesn't work ...
//  (X<int, less<int>>)( less<int>() )( nullptr, 123 );
//  ... and this also doesn't work ...
//  X<int, less<int>>( less<int>() )( nullptr, 123 );
}
```

Maybe this is special to my compiler (VC++ 2015).

Comment: What error do you get?  It compiles for me with MSVS 2015 update 3, g++, and clang

Comment: Compiles? With the comment of the two lines removed?

Comment: The unadorned version, `X<int, less<int>>( less<int>() )( nullptr, 123 );`, works with bleeding-edge Clang: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BAN6rK2g9w3GEigT

Comment: I assume you are getting the error `'less<int>': typedef cannot be used for function definition`? Don't make us guess what the error message is.

Comment: And also in C++03 GCC. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QALrTSCgQGoMwCdz

Comment: @BonitaMontero Ah.  I had to uncomment the line.  g++ and clang both compile line 3.  Line 2 should not work.  For MSVS I have to change `X<int, less<int>>( less<int>() )( nullptr, 123 );` to `X<int, less<int>>(less<int>{})(nullptr, 123);`.  I think it is something in MSVS's parsing that does not like it with `()`.